# How to add icon near arrow icon for JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

I would like to create `JComboBox` control similar with the URL textbox of Firefox. Does anyone know how to customize the textfield of the `JComboBox`. I want to add some icons on the `ALIGN.HORIZONTAL_RIGHT` near the arrow button of the `JComboBox`

---

Thanks for your very detail explanation. Actually I will combine `DefaultListCellRenderer` and add the icon to the combo box like following code

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        // Create icon "C"
        JButton jb = new JButton("C");
        jb.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        jb.setBounds(245, 2, 18, 18);

        // Create combo box
        String[] languages = new String[]{"Java", "C#", "PHP"};
        JComboBox jc = new JComboBox(languages);
        // jc.setEditable(true);
        jc.add(jb);

        getContentPane().add(jc);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 58));
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Main main = new Main();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                main.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But when I put `jc.setEditable(true)`; the combo editor hided my icon. I'm thinking another way to simulate Firefox awesome bar. Do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is completed  example that demonstrate it:

```
package com.demo.combo.icon;



import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class ShowConboWithIcons extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final ImageIcon INFO_ICON  = new ImageIcon("info.png");
private static final ImageIcon NONE_ICON  = new ImageIcon("none.png");
public final String NONE_STR = "None";
private final String INFO_STR = "Info";

private JComboBox comboBox;
private JPanel    topPanel;

private String[] str_arr = null; 


public ShowConboWithIcons(String[] str_arr) {
    this.str_arr = str_arr;     
}


public void createGUI(){

    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    setTitle("Demo");
    setLocation(200, 200);

    topPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    Map<Object, Icon> icons = new HashMap<Object, Icon>(); 

    icons.put(NONE_STR, NONE_ICON); 
    icons.put(INFO_STR, INFO_ICON); 

    comboBox = new JComboBox();
    comboBox.setRenderer(new IconListRenderer(icons));
    comboBox.addItem("None");

    for(String val : str_arr){
        comboBox.addItem(val);
    }

    topPanel.add(comboBox);

    super.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {           
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {              
            dispose();          
        }           
    }); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel( "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel" );   

    String[] str_arr = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

    ShowConboWithIcons T = new ShowConboWithIcons(str_arr);
    T.createGUI();
    T.setVisible(true);        
}


class IconListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{ 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Map<Object, Icon> icons = null; 

    public IconListRenderer(Map<Object, Icon> icons){ 
        this.icons = icons; 
    } 

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    { 
        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); 

        // Get icon to use for the list item value 
        Icon icon = icons.get(value); 

        if(!value.toString().equals(NONE_STR)){
            icon = icons.get(INFO_STR);
        }

        // Set icon to display for value 
        label.setIcon(icon); 
        return label; 
    } 
}
}
```

Preview:

[image: combo default mode:]

[image: combo select item:]

Answer (score 5):

To change how a component renders, you generally work with what are called `Renderer`s.

For combobox, look at how to create a [custom combobox renderer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer). Just a quick glance, but for your case, a simple configuration of [`DefaultListCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) may be enough, since you can set the `JLabel` properties to position the text to the image. If not, just extend from it.

Remember also that you have to set a model that includes the icon so that the combobox renderer can get it - might want to do a custom `ComboBoxModel` too, depending on your data object.

Comment: Hi aberrant80,

Thanks for your quick answer. I checked out the DefaultListCellRenderer, that will help me to customize the list item like Firefox.

But the other one to add the icon in the JComboBox textbox, i will use custom painting to draw an icon that should be on the right of the control.
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Thanks,
Minh

Comment: @minh, for the text box, you should see what you can do by creating a custom editor. there is some mention in the tutorial @aberrant80 posted.

Comment: DefaultListCellRenderer is essentially a JLabel. JLabel supports an icon in addition to the normal text. My guess is that it should simply retrieving the renderer and then setting the appropriate icon-to-text positioning/alignment andit might work.

Comment: it seems that @minh wants an editable combo box. the renderer will only solve the common case of displaying the uneditable list data. the problem still exists for the text editor. that is where my custom editor suggestion is coming from.

Comment: Ah right, I missed that. Minh, in the Sun's tutorial link I provided, just one section above, it explains about editable comboboxes. Doing setEditable(true) just might also achieve what you want, if you want it to be simply editable.