# Does anyone have sample code of JTable that shows Icon and String together in a same column?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I wonder if anyone can offer a simple example of JTable that shows Icon and String value together in a cell.

I can build a JTable having column either only with Icon or String, but not both in a cell together.

Hope anyone can give me a sample here...

My codes are attached,
I usually make code simpler before I post question, but don't know how fix it this time... forgive me that I attached

```
package jtableWithIcon;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

    public void fillColor(JTable t,JLabel l,boolean isSelected ){
    //setting the background and foreground when JLabel is selected
        if(isSelected){
            l.setBackground(t.getSelectionBackground());
            l.setForeground(t.getSelectionForeground());
        }
        else{
            l.setBackground(t.getBackground());
            l.setForeground(t.getForeground());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                                                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
        if(value instanceof JLabel){
            ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon();
            JLabel label = (JLabel)value;
            //you can add the image here

            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icon.png")));   
        //*****NullPointException occurs here in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"....
       //*********************************************

        label.setOpaque(true);
        fillColor(table,label,isSelected);

        return label;
    }
    else {
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
 }
}
```

---

```
package jtableWithIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class MainMyTableTest extends JFrame{

    public MainMyTableTest(String title){
        super(title);
        showGUI();
    }

    public void showGUI(){
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new MyModel());//invoking our custom model
        table.setDefaultRenderer(JLabel.class,  new Renderer());// for the rendering of cell
        JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(jp);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500,300);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainMyTableTest t = new MainMyTableTest("Table Custom");
    }
}
```

---

```
package jtableWithIcon;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

class MyModel extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel{

    Object[][] row = {{new JLabel("Row 1 Col 1"), "Row 1 Col 2", "Row 1 Col3"},
                      {new JLabel("Row 2 Col 1"), "Row 2 Col 2", "Row 2 Col3"},
                      {new JLabel("Row 3 Col 1"), "Row 3 Col 2", "Row 3 Col3"},
                      {new JLabel("Row 4 Col 1"), "Row 4 Col 2", "Row 4 Col3"}};

    Object[] col = {"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"};

    public MyModel (){

    //Adding columns
        for(Object c: col)
            this.addColumn(c);

    //Adding rows
        for(Object[] r: row)
            addRow(r);
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if(columnIndex == 0)
            return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();

        else 
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);

    }
}
```

These codes are captured from Internet...
I'm trying to understand how Render works by studying this..
but an error occurs at the Renderer class..

Comment: Please show us your best [mcve] code. If you haven't already done so, you'll want to look into creating your own JTable cell renderer, (although I would assume that your research would already have lead you in this direction).

Comment: sorry that I  just asked a sample.... now I attached the codes that I was working on.

Comment: It looks like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10785292/1140748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to make it work.

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icon.png")));
```

This line had to go with the below one.

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("icon.png));
```

Also, someone who wants to render the JLabel to put it on any components,
The answer is here [How to add icon near arrow icon for JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077571/how-to-add-icon-near-arrow-icon-for-jcombobox/1083812#1083812)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store a JLabel in the TableModel. A JLabel takes up too many resources.

Instead create a custom Object (lets say IconTextItem) with two properties: 1) text and 2) icon.

Then your custom renderer would look something like:

```
class IconTextRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        IconTextItem item = (IconTextItem)value;
        setText( item.getText );
        setIcon( item.getIcon );

        return this;
    }
}
```

And you add the renderer to the table with code like:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer( new IconTextRenderer );
```